# How can I tell which homebrew formulae are upgradable?

Tags: homebrew

I know when I `brew update`, it lists all `==> Updated Formulae`, but when I've updated several times without running `brew upgrade`, how do I get a list of all apps that could be upgraded?

Answer (score 414, accepted):

Per [homebrew code on github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cmd/outdated.rb), this shows all apps that can be updated:

```
brew outdated
```

`brew help` does not list the command, but it is documented in [`man brew`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage).

Comment: And `brew upgrade` if you want apply availables upgrades for all of your formulas (or `brew upgrade formula` for single package)

Comment: Note: You need to run `brew update` **before** you run `brew outdated` to get the latest list of updatable packages.

Comment: How can I update all the outdated packages? Can we use | or anything else?

Comment: @MahdiAmrollahi `brew upgrade` updates all outdated casks, formulae, etc.

Comment: @Pierz is correct! As of 2022 running `brew outdated` before `brew update` [will return nothing](https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/3205). Which seems counterintuitive, why run an update command **before** checking what needs to be updated? You might create a function that combines both commands and name it `brew outdated`

Comment: `brew outdated` with the latest brew already automatically runs `brew update --auto-update`...

Answer (score 50):

Since Homebrew 2.6.0 released in 2020.12.01, `brew outdated` behaves a little differently.

```sh
# update package repo
brew update

# list outdated pkgs, both formula and cask
brew outdated
# list formula only, the old behavior of 
#  `brew outdated` before brew 2.6.0
brew outdated --formula
# list cask only
brew outdated --cask
```

In Homebrew's jargon, a package is called a "Formula". Homebrew is not only manages TUI apps, it's also capable of managing GUI apps. A package for a GUI app is known as "Cask".

Before Homebrew 2.6.0, `brew outdated` only list formulae. Since 2.6.0 `brew outdated` both of formulae and casks.

Comment: This should (now) be the accepted answer. Without running `brew update` first, you do not get anything from `brew outdated`.

Comment: Note since we're talking about jargon: a "formula" is named so because it's a list of downloads and steps needed to install a specific application. It does not hold the binaries or get them from a central repository like a 'traditional' package manager.

Comment: @craig.kaminsky no more necessary, brew outdated with the latest brew already automatically runs brew update --auto-update

Comment: @Chris Do you have any reference for this new behavior? I can't find anything in the man pages nor in `brew outdated --help` (Homebrew 4.1.13).